# Mix jQuery, RSS and PHP withoutout refreshing.

Tags: php, jquery, rss

I'm currently trying to get my head around the jQuery language. I'm trying to make sort of a RSS validator. The idea is that the user types in RSS URL and then the jQuery checks if the RSS has an title. If it does it sends it to a PHP file which checks if it already exists in the database and then sends back the results to the original page. All without refreshing.

I can make it work so the jQuery sends the information to the php which checks if it exists and then sends the result back without refreshing.

The problem comes up when I try to implement the RSS jQuery function. I have tried to simply put it in the other jQuery but it just refreshes.

The form:

```
<form id="lets_add" action="" method="get">
            <input id="addurl" type="text" name="URL" value="URL"onfocus="searchinput();" onblur="searchinput2();" />
```

The jQuery code to pass it to the php, without the title:

```
$(function() {
$("#lets_add").bind('submit', function(){
    var value = $('#addurl').val();
    $.post('db_add.php',{value:value}, function(data){
        $("#val_add").html(data);

        });
        return false;
});
});
```

The php:

```
mysql_select_db ("members");
$term = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['value']);
$title = mysql_real_escpae_string(@$_POST['title']);

$ost = "SELECT * FROM linkdb WHERE URL = '$term' OR name = '$title'";

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($ost))){
     echo "The RSS exists in the database.";
}

else{ 
     echo "The RSS i validated, with title: " . $title;
}

mysql_close($con);
```

And the RSS title:

```
$.get('proxy.php?url='+$('#addurl').val(), function(d) {

    //find each 'item' in the file and parse it

        $(d).find('channel').each(function() { 
            var $channel = $(this);
            var title  = $channel.find('title:first').text();
```

Perhaps needless to say, there is a div with the `id="val_add"` which catches the echo..

Comment: `I'm currently trying to get my head around the jQuery language`. jQuery != a language. But rather a javascript library.

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript framework meant to ease client side programming in a more efficient way :)

Comment: Could you clarify how you call the "RSS title" fetch (and include the whole function, it seems snipped?), because chances are there's a "return false" missing somewhere on a submit or the like. Alternately there's a error -- that you miss because of the page refresh -- that breaks the JavaScript interpreter and proceeds to submit.

Comment: Like i said, I'm still learning the 'framework' so I searched the web for a RSS reader which used the URL to retrieve a feed and just added the title part. Don't know if i forgot something but there's no "return false" anyway. I got the `"$.get('proxy.php?url='+$('#addurl').val(), function(d)"` from: (http://visualrinse.com/2008/09/24/how-to-build-a-simple-rss-reader-with-jquery/) and builded the rest myself, which seems to work. All the help you give is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the title with jQuery I used cUrl to find it within the php page..